# Retrieve Rows Value to Textboxes C# & SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Do you have any ideas on how I can put this to rows:

[image]

in this texboxes?

[image]

or sooner 10 rows to 10 textboxes?

I only know is to retrieve one row:

```
if (Inventory.passQty == "1")
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP-ANJELLO\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = db_ADAPurchase; Persist Security Info = True; User Id = sa; Password = mm4;");
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM tbl_PurchaseRequest WHERE request_id = {0}", Inventory.passID);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        label_RID.Text = dr.GetString(0);
        label_Item1.Text = dr.GetString(1);
        txb_Title.Text = dr.GetString(2);
        cbx_vendor.Text = dr.GetString(3);
        txb_address.Text = dr.GetString(4);
        label_date.Text = dr.GetString(5);
        cbx_terms.Text = dr.GetString(6);
        txb_ITD1.Text = dr.GetString(7);
        txb_Qty1.Text = dr.GetSqlInt32(8).ToString();
        label_unit1.Text = dr.GetString(9);
        txb_UntP1.Text = dr.GetSqlInt32(10).ToString();
        txb_TotP1.Text = dr.GetSqlInt32(11).ToString();
        label_total.Text = dr.GetSqlInt32(12).ToString();
        txb_reqBy.Text = dr.GetString(13);
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

How do I make this to retrieve multiple rows in different textboxes?

Thanks for helping me!

PS: Sir @mohit-shrivastava can you please help me again?

Comment: Hahahah :D  Lemme try. **May be you can try `while` instead of `if`**

Comment: Could you please tell me the name of `Item Description` TextBoxes Name  how it looks like. Better you should choose a DataGridView Instead. The Grids are meant for this kind of data to be shown

Comment: The `Item Description` textboxes is the longest textboxes. I choose to show it to `TextBox` because the user will edit values from the db. After editing, save to db.

Comment: I try `while` but using it will stack the values in the same textbox. I want like 1st row > 1st ITD then 2nd row > 2nd ITD to 10 row > 10 ITD.

Comment: what is the name of the first row Item Description TextBox and then what is the name of second row  Item Description TextBox? You can do the editing part also in GridView.

Comment: ITD1 and ITD2 Sir

Comment: I want also to do it but I want a system that easily recognize by the user like he/she know how to manipulate the form even he/she see it  for the 1st time.

Comment: If you want the UI to be user friendly then you can make a double click on the grid to load the values in the form and then update the updated values in the grid and db. Else you have to write the lengthy and unmanageable code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this but GridView is instead a very good idea to implement this kind of situation.

```
if (Inventory.passQty == "1")
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = DESKTOP-ANJELLO\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = db_ADAPurchase; Persist Security Info = True; User Id = sa; Password = mm4;");
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM tbl_PurchaseRequest WHERE request_id = {0}", Inventory.passID);

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        label_RID.Text = dr.GetString(0);
        label_Item1.Text = dr.GetString(1);
        txb_Title.Text = dr.GetString(2);
        cbx_vendor.Text = dr.GetString(3);
        txb_address.Text = dr.GetString(4);
        label_date.Text = dr.GetString(5);
        cbx_terms.Text = dr.GetString(6);
        label_total.Text = dr.GetSqlInt32(12).ToString();
        txb_reqBy.Text = dr.GetString(13);
        int number = 1;
        do
        {
            TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find("txb_ITD" + number.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
            tb.Text = dr.GetString(7);
            TextBox tb1 = this.Controls.Find("txb_Qty" + number.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
            tb1.Text = dr.GetSqlInt32(8).ToString();
            TextBox tb2 = this.Controls.Find("label_unit" + number.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
            tb2.Text = dr.GetString(9);
            TextBox tb3 = this.Controls.Find("txb_UntP" + number.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
            tb3.Text = dr.GetSqlInt32(10).ToString();
            TextBox tb4 = this.Controls.Find("txb_TotP" + number.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
            tb4.Text = dr.GetSqlInt32(11).ToString();
            number++;
            //Since Query can pull more records than 10
            if(number>=10)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while(dr.Read())
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

This code will read the SQL Data as the way you were reading it and then fill all the textboxes which are supposed to be printed once. Liek `RequestID`, `Item`, `Title`, `Vendor` etc.. then comes to the loop. Now dr already have the first record so we dont want to read the dr again otherwise it will take the next record in the record set so we used `do-while` instead of while. Now We are trying to find the controls from [`Control.ControlCollection.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) and put the extracted values to the concerning textboxes.

Note: The Code has not been tested. but it is to give you the glimpse of what has to be done to get the output as expected.

Comment: Let me decipher your code Sir @mohit-shrivastava. The `Do-While` loop will read the db values by one item per column then transfer to textboxes of ITD, Qty, Unit, UntP and TotP. While `dr.Read` still reads, each texbox number values increases? Am I right?

Comment: And only stop when it reaches 10th ITD, Qty, Unit, UntP and TotP textboxes?

Comment: Where `FindControl` came from?

Comment: [Control.FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) to access a control from a function in a code-behind page, to access a control that is inside another container, or in other circumstances where the target control is not directly accessible to the caller.

Comment: @AnjelloJoshua Please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: No you did an awesome job in explaining the code. thus I just rephrase it in other words for another who wanted to get referenced from. But i also changed FindControl to `this.Controls.Find`

Comment: Nope. @AshishSrivastava TextBox will remain its enable and disable or readonly property as it is. The code is not manipulating it. If we want to change readonly to editable mode. We can do it once we found the textbox.

Comment: Sir @MohitShrivastava how about using `HasRows`?

Comment: What `HasRows`? Where? How? Are u talking about UI or SqlData ??

Answer (score 0):

i think for creating multiple rows by creating multiple server side textbox.you neeed jquery for that. that is much easy faster and reliable:

Steps You required :

1.Create a webservice that pull all rows from the database.
2.Bind table rows by loping the data from webservice.
3.Create a webservice to insert all data to databse.

Comment: it is a winform app :)

Comment: Sir it's a web app it's only windows app 

Comment: ok then generating multiple server side textbox is the only option.